# Android Meta-Data: Large int not seen as String

Tags: android, manifest

Android has the solution to define `meta-data` in the manifest. I think this is a very nice solution for people who are building SDK's. **Why?** Because if you have to define a certain set of keys in the String file it would be nicer to only set them in the Manifest. They are more in context with the application and its friendlier for the developer implementing your SDK in their project since they only have to add some *lines* in the **manifest** instead of editing two or more files for only an `api key/sender_id`.

**So to the point**

I want the user to place a large number in their manifest so I can retrieve it and retrieve it from the SDK.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.example.projectId"
        android:value="385167817594" />
```

This is my code for retrieving the Meta-data. Where META_PROJECT_ID = com.example.projectId

```
String pkgName = mContext.getPackageName();
Bundle bundle = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(pkgName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
String projectId = bundle.getString(META_PROJECT_ID);
```

This code works with all my other values defined in the manifest. But the fun part is, when retrieving values from the manifest it looks like some parsing is done inbetween. Even if I do `getString(..)` it will return an `int` and not a `String` since the projectId only contains numbers and is not `alphanumric`. If I add one letter to the projectId value defined in the manifest it will return a String. **Example:** 385167817594**a**

I think this is not a problem for the most of us. They will do getInt and then later convert it to String when necessary. **But** this int is too big. The Bundle isn't even showing the correct value in the debugger. Its showing a large negative number (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`) that probably indicates parsing went wrong?

**How did others do it?**

`Facebook` encountered the same problem i guess. What they did is the following:

**Manifest** (for example)

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.example.projectId"
        android:value="@string/project_id" />
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<string name="project_id">385167817594</string>
```

Does anyone know why `Facebook` decided to solve it like this? I mean now you have to edit two files and reference from the manifest to the Strings manifest.

Is there really no solution or is what Facebook did `best practice`?

For now i will do it like Facebook did, but im really curious if there is any solution out there and if what Facebook did is best practice

Answer (score 1):

Change the

```
<meta-data android:name="com.example.projectId" android:value="385167817594" />
```

to be

```
<meta-data android:name="com.example.projectId" android:value="38516781759\u0034" />
```

substitute the number 4 with its unicode equivalent \u0034

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it's not ideal for people who are gonna implement your SDK to tell them to subsitute their projectId.

Comment: This is a bad for building SDK, but I still use this trick with `Facebook`.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked this with Facebook SDK, they dont use it as an int, it is String.
check this below code from facebook sdk for Android.

```
public static String getMetadataApplicationId(Context context) {
    Validate.notNull(context, "context");

    try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (ai.metaData != null) {
            return ai.metaData.getString(Session.APPLICATION_ID_PROPERTY);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // if we can't find it in the manifest, just return null
    }

    return null;
}
```

if you want to use it then use it as a String. then try to convert it into double or long type. i hope this will help you.